# hostname: No address associated with hostname

Tags: networking, server, raspberrypi, hostname

Good day! I am using 20.04.3 Ubuntu server on my Raspberry Pi 4,

I am using my Rp4 as Pi-hole w/ unbound as well as a docker, everything went fine except for 1 which is the the title of my post

I did try the following

1. removing the resolv.conf `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf` and then create a new one `sudo nano /etc/resovl.conf`

   RESULT: nothing happend
2. I put this in my `/etc/host`

   ```
   10.124.10.20 homelab-ubuntu-server
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   ```

   RESULT: still getting the error

I'm running out of option on what to do with it.

*Note*: I always do a `sudo reboot now` every time i change my host and hostnames and I still see myself as a beginner in linux

**Additional Info:**

my netplan is setup like this:

```
ethernets: 
    eth0: 
      addresses:
        - 10.124.10.20/24 
      gateway4: 10.124.10.1
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [10.124.10.20] 
      optional: true
```

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear from your post where you get that error.

Comment: the error starts after the installation of Pi-hole, the problem just pops out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have time to troubleshoot again and I found the solution and it's all my mistake

I am editing the wrong file all along!! haha damn, it should be `/etc/hosts` not `/etc/host`

after editing the `/etc/hosts` and restarting the system, the hostname: No address associated with hostname is now gone